# Can we declare variable inside div tag in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following div:

```
 <div id="5" style=" display:none; " >               
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:schoolConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [class] where classid=4 "></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

As you can see i am giving the classid = 4 manually by myself in the where condition.What I want is to give it dynamically according to to click made.
What i am trying to do here is declare a variable inside div that will be assigned the value as per the click on the link and assign that variable to classid as classid=myvariable.

So my question is:

1.How to declare a variable inside div in asp.net?

2.How to assign classid=variable?

Comment: Your question is not clear what do want to achieve through it. Put what do want to do with the above code.

Comment: There is actualy no point in putting a DataSource control in a `div` as it is not a control that is renedered as HTML to the page, the way a GridView, for example would be.

Comment: @Jon P Actually what i want to do is make a simple website.For that i have to get data from database and display in the .aspx page.I am new to asp.net.I don't know how to achieve it so i am trying this,if there is a better way help me out.

Comment: You need to do a little more learning on how ASP.net works, particularly with DataBound controls. @3dd answer will help you, but understand that the parameter values won't be updated untill the page is posted back to the server and therfore whatever is depending on the DataSource won't be updated untill the new page is sent back to the browser. Generaly this won't be in response to clicking on a link, rather submitting a form of some description back to the server. Google some ASP.net DataBinding tutorials to get you started.

Comment: @ Jon P please can you provide me some references and links on how to display data from database and place them in the layout i desire.

Comment: All I would be doing is using Google as I described above, I'm sure that you can do that. Microsoft itslef has some fairly good getting started with ASP.net tutorials. StackOverflow isn't really the place to come for "I need a turorial for [Insert framework here]".  That is what Google/Bing/etc is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following article for an example of how this should be done

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z72eefad(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z72eefad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You're code could be written something like this

`SELECT * FROM [class] where classid=@classId`

Then declare the parameter using

`<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="classid" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
</SelectParameters>`